# Doctrine is not loading a class MappingException

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, autoload

I have a clean install of just Doctrine ORM

Please help I get MappingException for a Product class all the time

```
<?php

namespace src;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 */
class Product{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length = 5)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GenerateValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=2, name="product_code")
     */
    protected $code;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=10, name="product_name")
     */
    protected $name;

}
```

I have a regular bootstrap file

```
<?php
// bootstrap.php
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
require_once "src/Product.php";

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

$paths = array(__DIR__."/src");
$isDevMode = true;

$dbParams = array(
    'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
    'user'     => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'dbname'   => 'myDbName',
);

$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode);
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);

$theProduct = $entityManager->find("Product", 500);
```

And I have a composer with

```
{
  "require": {
    "doctrine/orm": "v2.5.10"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "src\\": "src/"
    }
  }
}
```

Folder Structure is 
[image]

I am running bootstrap.php

Whatever I do I always get Fatal error: Uncaught Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException: Class 'Product' does not exist in D:\projects\pp\vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException.php on line 96

Comment: Is your entity actually located in `__DIR__."/src"` ? Did you print that path and check if everything's correct? Is the autoloader configured correctly?

Comment: Yes the problem is that the path is correct, I have checked in several ways. I don't know what else to check.

Comment: Try adding `"autoload": {"psr-4": {"src\\": "src/"}}` to your composer.json (using `src` as a namespace is quite unusual though)

Comment: autoload inside composer json did not help. 
I had folder `entity` inside `src` which was namespaced `src\entity` but I removed everything to get clear understanding of what is going on, if by unusual you mean folder structure.

Comment: You might want to edit your question by appending your whole composer.json (or relevant parts) and folder structure.

Comment: I think it's problem of namespace, try to remove `namespace src;` or request entity manager by: `src\Product`. Better have `src/entities` folder and have entities without namespace. In this case doctrine will handle loading them. Autoloader may work in case if You do definitely: `use src\Product`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Doctrine Entity "Class not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147232/doctrine-entity-class-not-found)

Comment: @num8er I have seen it. It does not help me

Comment: @user3410843 then I don't know what's happening, try to debug with php's debugger to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: I have removed `namespace src;` and removed `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;`. Converted all `@ORM\Entity` and others to `@Entity` with similar changes in other doc blocks and everything started working. Can somebody explain what is the problem with my namespaces?

Comment: @num8er any ideas about namespaces ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues here

1)

createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration has a 5th parameter which is boolean $useSimpleAnnotationReader. So if you want to write something like this

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
```

past the 5th parameter false during config

```
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode, null, null, false);
```

Otherwise if you do not include Mapping, and @ORM in front it will work just fine with

```
/**
* @Entity
*/
```

2)

If you want to namespace your Entities you have to add namespace for your entities to your config

```
$config->addEntityNamespace('', 'src\entity');
```

First parameter is an alias (you can leave it empty or whatever you put should append in front of [:] in the next statement), now you can call

```
$theProduct = $entityManager->find(":Product", 500);
```